# Check out new branch from master with changes from another branch, which is branched out from master?

Tags: git

I have the following branches at the moment:

```
----------- master
   \---------------- feature
       ---------------- awesome-feature
```

I accidentally started working on something new, and I forgot to `git checkout master` and then `git checkout -b feature/new-feature`, so now all my new changes are on the `awesome-feature` branch. So now I want to do this:

```
----------- master
   \---------------- feature
       ---------------- awesome-feature
       ---------------- new-feature
```

So that all my new changes from `awesome-feature` are on the `new-feature` branch. Would the proper way to do that be:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature/new-feature
git stash apply
```

Or is there a better way (perhaps this doesn't even work)?

Comment: Try `git rebase`: `git checkout new-feature && git rebase master`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what `-` in your scheme means.

I assume that this are *commits*. In this case `git stash` and `git stash apply` are useless.

What you get with your sequence of commands is this:

```
           / new-feature
----------- master
   \---------------- feature
       ---------------- awesome-feature
```

It's more likely that you want this:

```
   /---------------- feature
  /------------------- awesome-feature
----------- master    \
           \...........+  new-feature
```

You get this when you append `git merge awesome-feature` to your sequence of commands. This does not "copy" the individual commits to `new-feature`.

However,

Usually you also want the actual state of "master" in your `awesome-feature` branch too before using it in another.

```
   /---------------- feature
----------- master
           \---------------- awesome-feature
                            \ new-feature
```

This you get by

```
git checkout awesome-feature
git rebase master
git checkout -b feature/new-feature
```

---

> If I simply git checkout new-feature from my current awesome-feature branch, they're connected. – MortenMoulder

Not really.

In git a branch is basically a "label on a commit". So yes, as long as you don't change any commit before the branch commit the branches look "connected". But you can *rebase* them separately.

However.

The final goal is to *integrate all branches into master*. The less differences you have in your branches the easier it is to combine them. Therefore this "relationship" of branches is something to desire rather than to avoid.

Comment: If I simply `git checkout new-feature` from my current `awesome-feature` branch, they're connected. I want to branch out from the master branch, so `new-feature` and `awesome-feature` have nothing in common.

The `-` are simply traversal lines, or whatever, to simply show I have 3 branches at the beginning: `master`, `feature` (child of master), and `awesome-feature` (child of feature), and so  show that I want a `new-feature` branch parallel with the `awesome-feature` branch (so they're both "children" of `feature` branch).